# What digital camera should I buy in order to use a Nikon Zoom-Nikkor 35-105mm f/:3.5-4.5 lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, zoom, camera

I have a Nikon Zoom-Nikkor 35-105MM 1:3.5-4.5 Lens f=35 and I'd like to know: which digital camera is compatible with this zoom?

thank you lots, 
Giorgia

Comment: Does it say anything else on the lens? Is it manual focus? Does it have any electrical contacts?

Comment: my camera has both automatic and manual focus, my camera is a Nikon AF 401X

Comment: Closely related: [Is the Nikon Zoom-Nikkor 35–105mm lens compatible with a D3400?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/is-the-nikon-zoom-nikkor-35-105mm-lens-compatible-with-a-d3400)

Comment: My question was about the lens, not the camera. I don't think the details you've given are enough to narrow it down to one specific lens, and without narrowing it down the question of compatibility has an element of guesswork.

Comment: AF-S? AF? AF-D? etc.?

Comment: How attached are you to this particular lens? Or is it more a matter of "well, I have it already..."?

Answer (score 3):

All Nikon F-mount lenses, apart from a few specialist lenses, can be used on almost all Nikon digital camera bodies that accept interchangeable lenses.

That includes all D-series DSLRs and, with a Nikon adapter, all Z-series or 1-series mirrorless/compact-systems-camera types.

Depending on the exact details, you may lose ability to use the autofocus capability and automatic exposure capability of the lens and body. You could still use the lens in manual-focus and/or manual-exposure modes.

---

> **Nikon Zoom-Nikkor 35-105MM 1:3.5-4.5**

There have been several different lenses with that description.

Given that you bought it around the same time as the F401x was on the market, it is almost certainly an F-mount full-frame lens but is probably an AF-D type lens.

[image: Nikkor 35-105]
An F mount lens (of that type) will fit on any Nikon F-mount digital camera body - including those with either full-frame or with APS sized sensors (Which Nikon call DX sensors for which F-mount DX lenses are designed).

To work on Nikon's Z-mount camera bodies, like the Z50, you need a special FTZ adapter.

On (second-hand) Nikon-1 bodies you'd need an FT1 adapter.

Your lens may be the type that requires a focus-drive motor in the camera body with a mechanical focus coupling for autofocus operation.
A few current digital cameras provide that drive, so on bodies that don't have focus motors, this type of lens can only be used in manual-focus mode ("M" or "MF" on the focus-select switch next to the lens mount).

[image]
Typical Auto-Focus / Manual focus switch

[image: F_mount digital body]
Nikon digital camera body with mechanical focus-drive coupling at 7 O'Clock position. The D610, D750, D850, D7500 for example, have this coupling and should work well with the lens pictured above.

See [Nikon AF Lens Designation](https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/na/NSG_article?articleNo=000026430&configured=1&lang=en_SG)

---

> **which digital camera is compatible with this zoom?**

I can't give you a full list, but I hope the above information will be helpful in finding a body.

If I was in your shoes and looking for a low-cost option, I'd sell your old lens on eBay and look at either a Z50 or D5600 with kit-lens.

Comment: "M" on the mode dial is for manual *exposure* mode, not manual focus. There's a different switch on the front of the camera for selecting focus. The choices are usually 'AF-C' (continuous AF), 'AF-S' (Single AF), and 'MF' (manual focus).

Comment: [defunct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defunct) = no longer living, existing, or functioning. Why would anyone bother using a lens on a dead, non-existent, or non-functioning camera?

Comment: @MichaelC Thanks for pointing out my mistake, corrected.

Comment: @xiota: Not sure where you are reading "defunct", I wrote "obsolete" back in rev 2. Maybe you have the same objection? I just mean "no longer in production and only available on the second hand market"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It was in [Revision 6](https://photo.stackexchange.com/revisions/112555/6). I have no problem with your use of [obsolete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolete) = of a kind or style no longer current, out of date. An adjective isn't really necessary. Suppose Nikon were to revive the Nikon 1. Would an FTZ adapter not be needed on newly produced bodies?

Answer (score 2):

I withdraw my previous answer. It now seems likely that the lens in question is the manual-focus AI-S lens, because the name stamped inside this lens’s filter ring is exactly the name given by the OP, whereas the AF variants have names that start with “AF Nikkor”.

For full compatibility* with this and all other AI/AI-S lenses, you need a camera that has an AI sensing tab in the lens mount. This includes every Nikon F-mount DSLR except the D3x00 family, the D5x00 family, and the D7500.

Nikon Z-series cameras can also use it with the FTZ adapter.

<sup>*</sup>Unfortunately, unlike the last film SLRs, no DSLR supports using an AI-S lens in shutter-priority (S) or program (P) autoexposure mode. Only aperture-priority (A) and manual (M) modes are supported.

Comment: To withdraw the previous answer, you can delete it.